# Using sphinx as a test framework

Tags: testing, flask, python-sphinx

In Sphinx, how can I call a javascript function using an anchor rather than hyperlinking to another page?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? What does "sphinx as a test framework" have to do with javascript functions?

Comment: I have used anchors to issue http requests but this results in opening a new page and navigates away from the Sphinx document.

I started over with the question since I got dinged for asking bad questions. I thought the new body would be more direct. I'm using the document as a framework for a test procedure and wish to issue web API calls which are embedded in the document. I thought that being able to call javascript would yield a working option.

Comment: If you have a problem, please show us how to reproduce it (see [mcve]). Without that information, I don't see how we can help.